# How to setup automated deployment from CodeCommit to a Lambda Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to "deploy" the content of a CodeCommit repository to a Lambda function (not an application).
In this particular case it's a simple copy/paste from source to destination.

I'm struggling to find a solution that doesn't involve setting up another Lambda function. From what I understand, there is a solution using CodeBuild and CloudFormation.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Alternatively, can you point to any good documentation?

P.S:

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59716661/aws-codepipline-update-lambda-function-source-using-s3-object) that seems to answer my question but the links in the relevant answer are outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me.

I setup a pipeline with CodeCommit as source and a Build Phase (no Deploy Phase).

The Build phase reads a buildspec.yml file which itself reads SAM template called template.yml. The SAM stack is created via CloudFormation.

I created an s3 bucket to hold the build artifacts.

Here is the sample buildspec.yml file:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the install phase...
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
    - aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yml 
                                  --s3-bucket <bucketname>
                                  --output-template-file newtemplate.yml
    - aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name <stackname>
                                --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
                                --template-file newtemplate.yml
                                --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<account number>:role/CloudFormationServiceRole
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed
```

Here is the sample template.yml file :

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: CloudFormation Stack for the lambda function

Resources:
# Details about the Lambda function
  <StackName>:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      CodeUri: src/
# Creates an alias named "live" for the function, and automatically publishes when you update the function.
      AutoPublishAlias: live
      DeploymentPreference:
# Specifies the deployment configuration
          Type: AllAtOnce
```

The file structure is :

```
.
├── src/
│   ├── node_modules/
│   └── index.js
├── builspec.yml
└── template.yml
```

Make sure you set the correct IAM policies for the CloudFormation and CodeBuild IAMs.

Answer (score 4):

You can build a [Code Commit Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-codecommit.html) with a `CodeBuild` Job where you `CodeCommit` repository has a `SAM` Template like below and you run

```sh
sam build && sam deploy
```

From the `codebuild` job.

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: A sample SAM template for deploying Lambda functions.

Resources:
# Details about the myDateTimeFunction Lambda function
  myDateTimeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: myDateTimeFunction.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
# Creates an alias named "live" for the function, and automatically publishes when you update the function.
      AutoPublishAlias: live
      DeploymentPreference:
# Specifies the deployment configuration
          Type: Linear10PercentEvery2Minutes
```

This documentation page describes the same [CodeCommit Rolling deployments for Lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-rolling-deployments.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it already makes it clearer ! 
Could you provide more info regarding the buildspec.yml file content to run "sam build & sam deploy" ? 
If I understand this correctly, I should add two files to codecommit : 
- buildspec.yml to trigger the sam template
- sam.yml which contains something like the code you gave
Is that correct ?

Comment: @Jarred correct, when you configure your ```codebuild``` job you just have the command ```sam build && sam deploy``` , give you have [aws sam](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) cli installed on the box for codebuild and the ```IAM Role``` for the ```codebuild```  has necessary permissions.