# How do I send Custom cypress report to slack thru aws code pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, slack, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Want to send a custom html report to slack from AWS Code Build, Configured a **buildspec.yml** file regarding cypress automation UI test and it will generate a html report. Now I need to send that report into specific slack channel. If someone helps me to do that, it will highly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install slackcat [1] in your build environment and issue required command to upload file in your Slack channel. Please don't hard code your Slack token in the buildspec and save it in Secrets Manager or Parameter Store [2].

Ref:

[1] https://github.com/rlister/slackcat

[2] [How to retrieve Secret Manager data in buildspec.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58216549/how-to-retrieve-secret-manager-data-in-buildspec-yaml)