# How to properly retrieve secrets from secret manager in buildspec (aws codebuild) and use them to query RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-codebuild

I have used this format

```
env:
   secrets-manager:

         DB_PASSWORD: Secret_Name_Env:password

         DB_USERNAME: Secret_Name_Env:username
```

I want secret name ENV to be dynamic so that I can change the environments accordingly.

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Your question lacks details and it is unclear.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58216549/how-to-retrieve-secret-manager-data-in-buildspec-yaml ?

Comment: @marcin I need to change secret manager name as per the environments like dev,qa ...

Comment: @YoucefLaidani in this answer they use parameter store ,but I need to use just secret manager

Comment: You can't change that. You have to parse the yaml file yourself before you use it, and do simple find-and-replace on it.